# Display additional information in cart page instead of checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, woothemes

I created an eCommerce using the **plugin woocommerce**. 
I need to get a few information from user **before checkout**, so used the WooCommerce Checkout Manager plugin and its working.
But this is displaying the additional information in checkout page.I need it to display it in cart page so that the user can proceed to checkout after filling the required informations like a feedback one.
How can i code it to display in cart page instead of checkout page?
 Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to hook into one of the following woocommerce functions depending on where you want the content to show on the cart:

```
woocommerce_after_cart
woocommerce_before_cart
woocommerce_before_cart_table
woocommerce_after_cart_table
```

I hope this helps and puts you in the right direction!