# Woocommerce add function to run after display items in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display message in cart page after items list. But i want to add it through a hook/function ,not with editing the cart page. 
Cant find exactly how to do it. but its probably looks something like:

```
add_action( 'print_cart', 'add_some_message' );
function add_some_message() {
     add_meta_box( 'message_title', 'message title', 'after' );
}
```

Its just a example, not familiar with woo functions.

Thanks.

Comment: see here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

Comment: Thanks,  @gauravkumar found there what i was looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709826/display-additional-information-in-cart-page-instead-of-checkout-page

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for gaurav kumar I found the hook here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/.
What i was looking for was:

```
my_function(){
     // my code to add after cart
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_contents', 'my_function');
```

In addition to woocommerce_after_cart_contents, their are: woocommerce_after_cart_table, woocommerce_after_cart_totals, woocommerce_after_cart. Each one acts in different part of the cart.
I'm writing the answer in case someone will have the same question.